# Collect word from list of Strings, while removing all letters and converting to columns

Tags: r, string, dataframe

I want to remove all letters from a string besides the characters that come after `STATION` and before the bracket `(` and store this as two separate columns.

I have tried to use this:

```
sub('.*STATION, (.*?)\\(.*', '',one)
```

However it returns the original data. While If I wanted to remove all letters:

```
str_remove_all(one, "[A-Z,a-z]")
```

Works however because of the previous code it removed the words that I need.

I have tried converting the list of Strings into a dataframe with 21 Columns (The number of columns before the newline `\n1`)

```
data.frame(one, ncol =21, byrow=TRUE))
```

However, this just creates 21 columns of the same data as opposed to separating them.

Expected outcome of the first row as example:

```
X1  X2  X3  X4  X5  X6  X7  X8  X9  X10  X11  X12  X13  X14  X15  X16  X17  X18  X19  X20  X21  X22 X23 

SWEDEN VAEXJOE  1860 534 -999999 1154 -999999 390 1481 584 -38 -556 -173 398 929 1411 1647 1383 1142 542 90 -440 
SWEDEN KARLSTAD 1860 454 -999999 1164 -999999 257 1580 542 -318 -752 -296 281 804 1498 1743 1493 1102 538 -34 -798
```

This is just an example as I have a list with 7000 of these data with many rows

Data:

```
list("EUROPEAN CLIMATE ASSESSMENT & DATASET (ECA&D), file created on: 14-06-2021\nTHESE DATA CAN BE USED FOR NON-COMMERCIAL RESEARCH AND EDUCATION PROVIDED THAT THE FOLLOWING SOURCE IS ACKNOWLEDGED: \n\nKlein Tank, A.M.G. and Coauthors, 2002. Daily dataset of 20th-century surface\nair temperature and precipitation series for the European Climate Assessment.\nInt. J. of Climatol., 22, 1441-1453.\nData and metadata available at http://www.ecad.eu\n\nFILE FORMAT (MISSING VALUE CODE = -999999):\n\nTHIS FILE HOLDS DATA FOR STATION SWEDEN                                   VAEXJOE                                  (STAID:      1)\nLATITUDE: dd:mm:ss +56:52:00\nLONGITUDE: ddd:mm:ss +014:48:00\nELEVATION: m  166\n\nDATA IS FOR INDEX Mean of daily mean temperature (TG) with unit 0.01 Temperature (&#176;C)\n\n01-06 SOUID: Source identifier\n08-11 YEAR : YYYY\n13-20 ANNUAL DATA VALUES\n21-28 WINTER HALF YEAR DATA VALUES\n29-36 SUMMER HALF YEAR DATA VALUES\n37-44 WINTER (DJF) DATA VALUES\n45-52 SPRING (MAM) DATA VALUES\n53-60 SUMMER (JJA) DATA VALUES\n61-68 AUTUMN (SON) DATA VALUES\n69-76 JANUARY DATA VALUES\netc. \n157-164 DECEMBER DATA VALUES\n\n1      1860 534     -999999 1154    -999999 390     1481    584     -38     -556    -173    398     929     1411    1647    1383    1142    542     90      -440", 
    "EUROPEAN CLIMATE ASSESSMENT & DATASET (ECA&D), file created on: 14-06-2021\nTHESE DATA CAN BE USED FOR NON-COMMERCIAL RESEARCH AND EDUCATION PROVIDED THAT THE FOLLOWING SOURCE IS ACKNOWLEDGED: \n\nKlein Tank, A.M.G. and Coauthors, 2002. Daily dataset of 20th-century surface\nair temperature and precipitation series for the European Climate Assessment.\nInt. J. of Climatol., 22, 1441-1453.\nData and metadata available at http://www.ecad.eu\n\nFILE FORMAT (MISSING VALUE CODE = -999999):\n\nTHIS FILE HOLDS DATA FOR STATION SWEDEN                                   KARLSTAD                                 (STAID:      6)\nLATITUDE: dd:mm:ss +59:21:00\nLONGITUDE: ddd:mm:ss +013:28:00\nELEVATION: m   46\n\nDATA IS FOR INDEX Mean of daily mean temperature (TG) with unit 0.01 Temperature (&#176;C)\n\n01-06 SOUID: Source identifier\n08-11 YEAR : YYYY\n13-20 ANNUAL DATA VALUES\n21-28 WINTER HALF YEAR DATA VALUES\n29-36 SUMMER HALF YEAR DATA VALUES\n37-44 WINTER (DJF) DATA VALUES\n45-52 SPRING (MAM) DATA VALUES\n53-60 SUMMER (JJA) DATA VALUES\n61-68 AUTUMN (SON) DATA VALUES\n69-76 JANUARY DATA VALUES\netc. \n157-164 DECEMBER DATA VALUES\n\n6      1860 454     -999999 1164    -999999 257     1580    542     -318    -752    -296    281     804     1498    1743    1493    1102    538     -34     -798")
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are dealing with string values, holding it as a character vector would be more convenient than a list.

```r
x <- c("EUROPEAN CLIMATE ASSESSMENT & DATASET (ECA&D), file created on: 14-06-2021\nTHESE DATA CAN BE USED FOR NON-COMMERCIAL RESEARCH AND EDUCATION PROVIDED THAT THE FOLLOWING SOURCE IS ACKNOWLEDGED: \n\nKlein Tank, A.M.G. and Coauthors, 2002. Daily dataset of 20th-century surface\nair temperature and precipitation series for the European Climate Assessment.\nInt. J. of Climatol., 22, 1441-1453.\nData and metadata available at http://www.ecad.eu\n\nFILE FORMAT (MISSING VALUE CODE = -999999):\n\nTHIS FILE HOLDS DATA FOR STATION SWEDEN                                   VAEXJOE                                  (STAID:      1)\nLATITUDE: dd:mm:ss +56:52:00\nLONGITUDE: ddd:mm:ss +014:48:00\nELEVATION: m  166\n\nDATA IS FOR INDEX Mean of daily mean temperature (TG) with unit 0.01 Temperature (&#176;C)\n\n01-06 SOUID: Source identifier\n08-11 YEAR : YYYY\n13-20 ANNUAL DATA VALUES\n21-28 WINTER HALF YEAR DATA VALUES\n29-36 SUMMER HALF YEAR DATA VALUES\n37-44 WINTER (DJF) DATA VALUES\n45-52 SPRING (MAM) DATA VALUES\n53-60 SUMMER (JJA) DATA VALUES\n61-68 AUTUMN (SON) DATA VALUES\n69-76 JANUARY DATA VALUES\netc. \n157-164 DECEMBER DATA VALUES\n\n1      1860 534     -999999 1154    -999999 390     1481    584     -38     -556    -173    398     929     1411    1647    1383    1142    542     90      -440", 
       "EUROPEAN CLIMATE ASSESSMENT & DATASET (ECA&D), file created on: 14-06-2021\nTHESE DATA CAN BE USED FOR NON-COMMERCIAL RESEARCH AND EDUCATION PROVIDED THAT THE FOLLOWING SOURCE IS ACKNOWLEDGED: \n\nKlein Tank, A.M.G. and Coauthors, 2002. Daily dataset of 20th-century surface\nair temperature and precipitation series for the European Climate Assessment.\nInt. J. of Climatol., 22, 1441-1453.\nData and metadata available at http://www.ecad.eu\n\nFILE FORMAT (MISSING VALUE CODE = -999999):\n\nTHIS FILE HOLDS DATA FOR STATION SWEDEN                                   KARLSTAD                                 (STAID:      6)\nLATITUDE: dd:mm:ss +59:21:00\nLONGITUDE: ddd:mm:ss +013:28:00\nELEVATION: m   46\n\nDATA IS FOR INDEX Mean of daily mean temperature (TG) with unit 0.01 Temperature (&#176;C)\n\n01-06 SOUID: Source identifier\n08-11 YEAR : YYYY\n13-20 ANNUAL DATA VALUES\n21-28 WINTER HALF YEAR DATA VALUES\n29-36 SUMMER HALF YEAR DATA VALUES\n37-44 WINTER (DJF) DATA VALUES\n45-52 SPRING (MAM) DATA VALUES\n53-60 SUMMER (JJA) DATA VALUES\n61-68 AUTUMN (SON) DATA VALUES\n69-76 JANUARY DATA VALUES\netc. \n157-164 DECEMBER DATA VALUES\n\n6      1860 454     -999999 1164    -999999 257     1580    542     -318    -752    -296    281     804     1498    1743    1493    1102    538     -34     -798")
```

With this data, you can extract the value you want using `stringr` library.
I think the purpose of each step is self-explanatory.

```r
library(stringr)

# get station names
res1 <- str_extract(x, "STATION [^\\(]*") %>%
  str_replace_all(" +", " ") %>% 
  str_replace("^STATION", "") %>% 
  str_trim() %>%
  as.data.frame()
res1

# get value parts
res2 <- str_extract(x, "[^\n]*$") %>%
  str_split(" +") %>% 
  sapply(as.numeric) %>% 
  t() %>%
  as.data.frame()
res2

# combine the two
out <- cbind(res1, res2)
out
```

The result:

```r
                . V1   V2  V3      V4   V5      V6  V7   V8  V9  V10  V11  V12 V13 V14  V15  V16  V17  V18 V19 V20  V21
1  SWEDEN VAEXJOE  1 1860 534 -999999 1154 -999999 390 1481 584  -38 -556 -173 398 929 1411 1647 1383 1142 542  90 -440
2 SWEDEN KARLSTAD  6 1860 454 -999999 1164 -999999 257 1580 542 -318 -752 -296 281 804 1498 1743 1493 1102 538 -34 -798
```

You may not need the first number (V1 column) but removing it should be easy.

Comment: When I get to ```str_extract(x, "[^\n]*$")``` it removes all the new-spaces and returns only the last 21 columns and removes the rest. How to overcome this?

Comment: I thought this is what you wanted to do from the expected outcomes you posted. If this is not true, please update the post.

Answer (score 0):

i suppose you want to extract 2 parts from string: station & numbers

first:

```
library(stringr)

# station
str_squish(
  word(
    word(your_string, 2, sep = fixed("STATION")), ## separate 2nd part of string ( after 'STATION' )
    1, sep = fixed("(")  ## separate 1st part of above ( before '(' )
  )
)
```

if '*DATA VALUES\n\n*' could be used as another pathern, that will help to separate *numbers*.

So here is the
second:

```
library(stringr)

# numbers
str_trim(
  word(your_string, 2, sep = ("DATA VALUES\n\n[0-9]")) ## separate 2nd part of string
)
```